# Copy filled columns over to empty fields in another column in same row

Tags: excel, outlook

I have an exported Outlook contact list which is full of some 1800 emails. The email field in one column (Col A) is only filled in on about half of the contacts, while another column (Col B) for "displayed name" contains email addresses for other contacts. However, the "displayed name" columns also contain other data in addition to the email addresses, so I would like to avoid over-writing the existing emails in Col A.

So, I would like to find a way to fill empty fields only in Col A with data from Col B. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to put everything in the Col. B cell into the empty Col. A cell? Or just specific data in the Col. B cell into the empty Col. A cell?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to just pull the email address from Col. B. Currently the Col. B cells looks like "Firstname Lastname (email@address.com)".

Comment: I editted my foreach loop to take only the email address from the string in Column B. It specifically searches for "(" to know where to begin

Comment: Hugo's answer will work for you now, you need commas instead of semi-colons and it has been editted

Comment: Thank you for your expertise Mike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to put everything from Col. B into empty Col. A then you can use this VBA code in a macro:

---

```
    Sub macro1()

    Dim theSheet As Worksheet
    Dim theRange As Range
    Dim emailLocation As Integer
    Dim output As String

    Set theSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set theRange = Range("A1:A" & theSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)


    For Each theCell In theRange

        If theCell = "" Then

            emailLocation = InStr(1, theCell.Offset(0, 1), "(")
            output = Mid(theCell.Offset(0, 1), emailLocation)
            theCell.Value = output

        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

This macro should work no matter how many rows of data a sheet contains

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is on the money!

Comment: @user1712390 welcome! don't forget to select an answer to your question and glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

In a third column, put this code....

```
=IF(A1 <> "",A1,B1)
```

then, apply it for all the 1800 rows.

Comment: +1 for a good concise and easy-to-use solution :)

Comment: Excel doesn't seem to agree with the double quotes and produces an error when I try to use the formula.  :(

Comment: @user1712390, `=IF(A1 <> "",A1,B1) ` is what you should use. the semi-colons are incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the ISBLANK function nested within the if statement and concatenate the two columns in a third column like so: =CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK(A2),B2,A2),B2)